# Updata mysql table using a form with variable for unique table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form which i fill in a number and then the right database is updated. this is not working!

The variable gets posted (i had inserted 3 you see this in the error but its not updating) 
i get this error? Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''3'_xyz_ips_short_code set content = replace(content,'eten','string_to_replace' at line 1

```
<textarea name="dbnaamsite" placeholder="3" cols="10" rows="1"></textarea>

 $dbnaamsite = $_POST['dbnaamsite'];

$sql = "update wp_'$dbnaamsite'_xyz_ips_short_code 
        set content = replace(content,'eten','string_to_replace')";
//mysql_real_escape_string($formPostTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
$sql = "update `wp_".$dbnaamsite."_xyz_íp_short_code` set content = replace(content,'eten','string_to_replace')";
```

Comment: do you maybe know how to replace multiple content values? i have now this code: $sql = "update wp_".$dbnaamsite."_xyz_ips_short_code set content = replace(content,'eten1','$extra2'), (content,'eten2','$extra3')"; but no suprise not working : )

Comment: Okay i will do this later. I dont see a button now.

Comment: @ABBER just click to arrow-up button if you think this answer is helpful :D